# node.js download image with unknown extension from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

My issue is download image from given link, but there is one trouble - I dont know image extension(bmp, jpg, png etc.)
I am using request module, and succesfully download  image of png extension:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var url = 'www.images.com/image01.';
request(url+ '.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./image.png'));
```

But what to do when I dont know image extension. I think maybe I can check responce and if it's = '404' , then second try to download  image from: *url + '.[another extension]'* and so on. By its look likes callback hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Request to the URL, check the **Content-type** in the header of the request for the Mime-type of the file. You can have a file in your project, called **mime-types.js**

Where you download the file, you can make a request of that file:

```
    var mime = request('mime-types.js');
```

And the content of your mime-types.js file should be something like this

```
    const JPG = "image/jpeg";
    module.exports = {
          JPG: JPG
    }
```

Then you can switch between the different mime-types you have and the result of the request.

You can find mime-types here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image

Comment: did you mean  var mime = require('mime-types.js'); ?

Comment: I did! Thank you MeetJoeBlack

Answer (score 0):

Perform `HEAD` requests and check HTTP response message `Content-Type` header. It should include one of the [specified MIME-types for images](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_image).